# Design pattern to ensure that a method A is called before method B

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a sample(incomplete) class like

```
class ABC{   
public:      
    void login();      
    void query_users();       
    //other methods  
private:      
    //member data
}
```

This class should be used in a way that login needs to be called first and then only other methods like query_users, etc., can be called. Login sets some private member data for the other methods to use. Is there any simpler way to achieve this other than calling a function that checks if the member data is set at the start of every other method in the class?

Comment: I would suggest that checking some data-members have been set is the safe thing to do.

Comment: I would suggest a single state variable

Comment: Of course, the other way is to have two objects. The one that creates the ABC object also calls the login method. This outer object is the only one that can provide an ABC object.

Comment: I was writing something about possibly using an annotation, then I read Mats Petersson's comment - I like that approach.  Basically use the builder pattern or a factory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two general approach I know of, and they differ a good bit. You'll have to pick the appropriate mechanism for the task - in standard class-based OO languages (e.g. Java/C++/C#/Python), they are the only two approaches I know of. (There may be other approaches in different paradigms that I am unfamiliar with.)

#### 1. Check the state.

This is done in many classes already that have to track the state of the system/backing resource. Two common examples are (file) stream and database connections.

A "template" might look like:

```
void Logon(credentials) { ..; loggedOn = true }
void DieUnlessLoggedIn { if (!loggedOn) { throw .. } }
void DoStuff () { DieUnlessLoggedIn(); .. }
```

While the above approach is pretty generic, some languages may support invariants (Eiffel), decorations (Python), annotations, AOP, or other assertion mechanisms.

*This approach is useful for dynamic state in a mutable world*: e.g. what happens after "Logout"? The state for `DoStuff` is invalid again until a re-logon (if it's allowed). However, this approach cannot be used for compile-time checks in general in mainstream OOP languages because the run-time state simply is not available at compile-time.

#### 2. Use multiple types to represent state.

Create two separate types, such that type ServiceLogon (method `Logon`) creates ServiceAccess (method `DoStuff`). Thus `DoStuff` can only be called (on type ServiceAccess) after created from `Logon` (on ServiceLogon). This works well to enforce calling order semantics in static languages with member hiding - because programs won't compile if it's wrong.

```
login = new ServiceLogon(credentials)
access = login.Logon();
access.DoStuff();        // can't be called before obtained via Logon
```

Using the type to encode additional state *can* be overly complex as it can fracture a class-based type system, but is useful in "builder" and "repository" patterns and such; basically, ask *if the type warrants being split to maintain SRP, then considering this approach*.

*This approach cannot handle things like "logout" entirely without incorporating state checking* as type ServiceAccess would (in the clean sense) always represent the same state due to it being encoded in the type.

#### 1. & 2. Use state checking *and* state/role-specific types.

A hybrid is totally acceptable, of course, and the above two approaches are not mutually exclusive. It may make sense to separate the roles making one type (and thus methods invoked upon it) dependent upon another method while still checking runtime state as appropriate. As per above, #1 is really good for runtime guards (which can be highly dynamic) while #2 can enforce certain rules at compile-time.

Comment: I have to agree with answer #2, if you use this process the compiler can actually catch this problem before runtime even happens because it's impossible to complete in the incorrect order.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create instances of ABC form a static factory method that returns the instance you can use. In pseudo-code:

```
abc = ABC.login(); //sets all the state
users = abc.query_users();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the best way but you can make `login()` private and call it as part of the constructor, which would ensure that `login()` is called at time of object creation itself and after that only any other functions can be called (unless you have static functions)

```
class ABC{   
public ABC(credentials){
    login(credentails);
}
public:           
    void query_users();       
    //other methods  
private:      
    void login(); 
    //member data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will already work first when it goes from the top down. If you want to make sure that login is successful then call the other methods from inside the login() method.

like:

```
public void login(){
  //do login code
    if(//code for login check){
         //run other methods
    }
    else{
        login(); //re-run login workings
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a dangerous skeleton for a login function :p

Comment: If you set a if to check it's only done ~3 iterations or something and then cancel it should get the job done recursively :P

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to follow good patterns you might try making as many of your classes immutable as possible.

This would imply that your constructor sets the total state (does the entire login) and then the order of the method calls is totally irrelevant.